# External User Login NOT Successful but Salesforce registers as Successful

Tags: user, customer-community, login

We have a Community portal for external users. When an external user first registers, they must set a password. After doing so, they are redirected to the login page for the Community. They then enter their username and password and it redirects them to the login page, over and over again.

When I look at the log for those external users, they all show 'SUCCESS'. I have no idea why this would be happening. I'm assuming their is a place in Communities to redirect a user to a specific page once they've logged in, and I'm also assuming someone set that to the login page. I can't find anything like that though.

Does anyone have any ideas on what might be causing this bug?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is not a community issue. Have you setup the home page and other page variations correctly inside the community

Comment: I didn't set them up but when in the community the pages look set up correctly.